# Get true label values in custom loss function in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, tensor

I just implemented a custom loss function for my sequential keras model. In the loss function I want to get the values of `y_t`, the `Tensor` that is fed in `batch_size` and do some math with those values:

```
def lossFunction(y_t, u):
    # 'y_t' shape is (batch_size, 500)
    # 'u' shape is (batch_size, 256) (output of last layer)
    y_t_temp = y_t[:,3:y_t.shape[1]]

    vectors=[] 
    for record in K.get_value(y_t_temp):
        # computeVector is a function that return np array of shape (500, 256) based on the input values
        vectors.append(computeVector(record))
    # the final 'vectors' shape should be (batch_size, 500, 256)
    vectors=np.array(vectors)
    vTens = K.variable(vectors) 
    u = tf.expand_dims(u, axis=K.ndim(u) if 1 == K.ndim(u) - 1 else K.ndim(u))
    dotResult = K.batch_dot(u,vTens,axes=[1,2])
    p = K.exp(dotResult)
    p = tf.reshape(p, [batch_size,500])
    sp = K.sum(p,axis=1)
    sp = K.expand_dims(sp, axis=1)
    sp = K.tile(sp,(1, 500))

    soft = p/sp
    soft=K.clip(soft, 0.0000001, 0.9999999)
    obj = K.categorical_crossentropy(soft, y_t)
    return obj
```

but with this loss function I get this error:

```
 'You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'dense_3_target' with dtype float
 [[Node: dense_3_target = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]'
```

I know that the problem is in the operation `K.get_value(y_t_temp)`, but I need to get the values to compute a vector for that label record as you see in for loop.

I just want to know how can I get fed `y_t` values in the loss function, or how can I implement this logic in another way.

The reason that I saved extra information in `y_t` is that I want to produce `vectors` array with those information for the fed batch_size of the train data. I can produce `vectors` array outside of the loss function for all the train data and pass it to the loss function, but the problem is that the loss function is fed with batch_size of the train data each time and that batch_size records are generated random from the train data as I know and I don't know how to filter the `vectors` array for those fed data in loss function, as a result I came to this solution to make `vectors` array in loss function based on some extra information for the batch_size data and I found no way but to save that extra information in `y_t` and by getting values of `y_t` I can handle my problem. so I really appreciate if there is any other way to either filter `vectors` array for fed batch_size of the train data by finding the index of the fed data in loss function or any other way to pass the corresponding filterd `vectors` array to loss function in some way.

I really appreciate your help or any other solution to implement my logic.

Comment: if you can't express the logic as part of the computation graph it is unlikely that it will work since keras dry-runs the graph and thus you'll get the error. Maybe you can shed some light on what "logic in here" entails and we can help you to express this as part of the graph.

Comment: I just edited my question and mention the logic complete.